# Transfer file from Mac/PC to iPhone App Document folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to transfer file from system (mac/Pc), which is present on my iPhone wifi network, to the document folder of my iPhone App.The scenario of my App is this, it will browse the system which are present in it's network. select any file(such as .pdf or ,docx) from that system(mac/Pc), copy it into the document folder of the APP and than use it with in the APP.During my search i come across the link [iPhone : Transfer of files from Mac/Pc to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242419/iphone-transfer-of-files-from-mac-pc-to-app) i have not found the detail instruction document, how to use it. Is Apple support any API or farm work to do this ? Please guide me

Answer (score 6):

This is called [iTunes file sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094). In the most simple way, you simply set the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key in your `Info.plist` file to `YES`. See for example [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app).

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting itunes is not a simple task but I recommend you a clever and easier solution:
Implement a simple webserver on your iOS app. Write a windows application which will connect to your iOS app through wifi network. Then transfer the necessary files this way: you will send a file to you app, then your app should save it in documents directory.