# Upload files from http to iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http

I want to be able in my app to upload files from my computer(windows,mac...) to the iPhone,so i an looking for a source code in objective-c that open server on iPhone,

but my question is, how i implement an upload from my computer to the device?

Edit

---

I want to upload the file from a computer that is on the same Network like the device,
something like :
the user will open browser and select a file and it will be upload to the device.

i found CocoaHTTPServer but i really didn't understand how to upload a file to the iPhone with this.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to download from the Mac/Pc to the device, instead of uploading to it?

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242419/iphone-transfer-of-files-from-mac-pc-to-app

Comment: i saw this post,but they didn't add nothing about upload files...

Comment: Take a look here: http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/03/cocoahttpserver-http-server-file-upload.html

Answer (score 0):

1. you probably want to upload the file to FTP-server, that shouldn't be a problem.
2. set up a webservice or json on your server to know what changed, or should be downloaded (depends heavily on your business logic of your app) - it could also be a static textfile
3. now the problem is how the app knows that there is are new files.

   - option 1: poll server if user presses a button or on every app start, etc.
   - option 2: send push notification to your iPhone app, if there are new file.

polling the server would be very easy to implement, compared to sending push notification.

---

**EDIT:** 
alright i read your edited post. hosting a local webserver on an iphone sounds still weird to me.

another possible solution, that could work for you - if you only want to transfer only a few and rather small files:

- enable [Document Interaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403) in your app.
- this would allow the user to send the file by mail to your iphone and open the document with your app with the "open in..." dialog .